# Select2 box Dropdown Down Arrow UI issue

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I am using select2 box library for dropdown.

**issue:**

[image]

I have set multiple property in **select Tag** and I want set chevron-up and chevron-down arrow in dropdown like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

i know its long time after post but maybe someone will look for it in future

i just added a rule for multiple select2 element :

```
.select2-selection--multiple:after{
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 right:10px;
 top:15px;
 width:0;
 height:0;
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-top: 5px solid #888;
}
```